# Jquery Looping function to copy from child and insert to parentadjacent div across page

Tags: jquery, loops, blogs

I'm new to coding with Jquery and have hit a roadblock when trying to get the following - which is intended for blogs/news sites- to work -

### HTML

```
  <div id="dog"></div>
  <div id="cat">
  <h1 id="food">text1</h1>
  </div>
```

```
  <div id="dog"></div>
  <div id="cat">
  <h1 id="food">text2</h1>
  </div>
```

etc / ID's are repeating to simulate how the html will appear on the blogs front end

---

### JQUERY

since i only know a little this is as far as i was able to get with jsfiddle

```
var a = $('#food').html();
var b = $('#dog').html(a);
```

---

using this I'm able to get the text ("text1") from inside cat and copy paste it inside its parents adjacent element, dog.

since this is meant for a blog/news type site i need this to occur for every instance of house and also without messing with classes ideally, the only possible exception to classes being that of the h1 class.

secondly this needs to be able to copy any text from inside the h1 id of "cat", BUT apply certain css to certain values of text e.g. unique css for 'news' 'column title 2' etc - I'm familiar with css so I don't need it to do the css in jquery and would prefer if it would direct the certain unique values of text to appropriate css values.

please help as I've been stuck on this for days now with further jquery stuff to apply to the site still :(.

Comment: Duplicated id's are not valid, they should be unique. Try using classes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean up your markup so that elements have unique IDs (ideally by using classes).  However, you can still do it with the id attribute selector if absolutely necessary:

```
$("[id=food]").each(function () {
   $(this).parent().prev('[id=dog]').html($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: the reason I put in two of the same id was to simulate how the html would work on the blog front end side of things